# how to intent activity A to activity B in data binding(MVVM) in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, kotlin

how to put intent form activity-A to Activity-B from Button1 and Activity-A to Activity-C from Button2 in DataBinding(MVVM model) from activity A in Android.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    public static final int start_status = 1;
    public static final int  intent_status = 2;
    public static int current_status = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LoginViewModel loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        binding.setLoginViewModel(loginViewModel);

        loginViewModel.getUser().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable User loginUser) {
                switch (current_status){
                    case start_status :
                        Intent intentt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intentt);
                        break;

                    case intent_status :
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }

                Intent intentt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intentt);



            }
        });


    }


}
```

Comment: i put  loginViewModel.getUser().observe(this, new Observer<User>()  and in onChange i put startactivity with status code in switch case but its not working.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add some additional info, don't post code in comments

Comment: Please post code here.

Comment: please see code above @Jaymin

Comment: @yuvrajsinh, can you please post your XML File along with it?